# How do I sum a specific column with group by and also sum a specific column without group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sample table here, the columns are `transaction_id`, `total_amount`, `collected_amount`.

| transaction_id | total_amount | collected_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 60 |
| 1 | 100 | 40 |
| 2 | 40 | 30 |
| 2 | 40 | 10 |
| 3 | 50 | 50 |
| 4 | 20 | 20 |

[table_image_for_quick_access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKLah.png)

I just want a result to get the sum of total_amount but with a group by with transaction_id. And also the sum of collected_amount (without group by, just use the SQL SUM function)

Here is the expected output.

| total_amount | collected_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 210 | 210 |

[expected_output_quick_access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCgBH.png)

As you can see, in total_amount column, it is like a query of

```
SUM(total_amount) from sample_table GROUP BY transaction_id
```

While in collected_amount on the expected output, the query is like

```
SUM(collected_amount) from sample_table
```

Thank you!

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Ok. I'll convert it to text. 

On your other question, it is mysql.

Comment: @DaleK I already corrected the tags sir. Thank you for your notif. I also update the question sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest aggregating twice:

```
select sum(total_amount), sum(collected_amount)
from (select transaction_id, total_amount, sum(collected_amount) as collected_amount
      from t
      group by transaction_id, total_amount
     ) tt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Summing the collected amount will provide a scalar result. Your grouping and summing will provide N number of records in the results, where N is equal to the unique transaction IDs. Thus you cannot combine the two into one query. However, you can run a nested query, which I generally avoid doing as it can be inefficient.

```
select
    transaction_id,
    sum(total_amount),
    (select sum(collected_amount) from sample_table)
from sample_table
group by transaction_id;
```

The other alternative is to try the `OVER` statement in MySQL.

```
select
    transaction_id,
    sum(total_amount) over(partition by transaction_id) total_amount,
    sum(collected_amount) over() collected_amount
from sample_table;
```